# Clarification of hard to understand Japanese Mahjong rule

Tags: terminology

This one probably needs a Japanese *and* Mahjong expert to decipher:

> （３）全局を一ハン（飜）しばりとし、二ハン場とする。

This is the third rule about the basic game setup of (my version of) the official Japanese Mahjong Tournament rules. A 局 *kyoku* is one round, a ハン／飜 *han* is a type of multiplier used in scoring. So far so good, but I have no idea what this rule is trying to convey. There's no further context in the immediately preceding or following rules. Can somebody tell me what this means?

Comment: I do not think that this is in scope.  The essence of this question is “What do 一飜縛り and 二飜場 mean?” and it is a question about the Mahjong terms which just happen to be in Japanese.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

一飜縛り【いーはんしばり】: your hand must be worth one han before you can declare a win.

二ハン場、I think, is a reference to 場【ば】ゾロ which is an additional two han given when calculating the score (two han is usual, at least).

とし is just the stem form of とする, so it's laying out these two rules, which apply to every round.

Comment: I see, now it's starting to make sense. So basically this rule says "For all games, 1 *han* is the minimum requirement and 2 is the base multiplier (*bazoro*)."?